# Creating a DataSet from XML that has 1 table and 0 rows

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I am currently creating a `DataSet` from an XML stream using this

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(xml);
```

I tried this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Which creates a `DataSet` where `Tables[0]` is a table called "NewDataSet" with 1 column called "Table" and 1 row where the value of "Table" is "".  I then tried just this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
</NewDataSet>
```

But this creates a DataSet with no tables. How do I create a DataSet with 1 table called "Table" with 1 column, but now rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. ReadXml and WriteXml read/write only data, not structure of the whole dataset/datatable/columns/etc-schema.

My suggestion is to first read the schema from a seperate schema file with the function [ReadXmlSchema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxmlschema(v=vs.110).aspx) and than read the data file.

Your schema could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema id="MyDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="MyDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="MyDataTable">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="MyDataColumn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```